# @Conditional not working on inherited classes?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a simple class annotated with `@Conditional(MyCondition.class)`

e.g.:

```
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public class MyBean {
  ...
}
```

Then I have a configuration bean which extends this bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends MyBean {
  ...
}
```

It seems that the `@Conditional` is being ignored and the `@Configuration` is always processed no matter how the condition would resolve (it's not even called)

As soon as I move the `@Conditional` annotation to the `MyConfig` everything works as expected.

From the doc:

> The @Conditional annotation may be used in any of the following ways:
>
> - as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly
>     annotated with @Component, including @Configuration classes
> - as a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype
>     annotations
> - as a method-level annotation on any @Bean method

I would assume the first point applies here, i.e. `MyConfig` is indirectly annotated with `@Configuration`. Or does the *indirectly* refer to other annotations which are annotated with `@Conditional`?

Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) of `@Conditional`

> NOTE: @Conditional annotations are not inherited; any conditions from superclasses or from overridden methods are not being considered.

The `@Conditional` annotation isn't `@Inherited` and as such it isn't visible on sub classes.

Comment: Right, missed that in the doc, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Why is this disallowed?